# Gradient descend: What is the correlation of the different terms in the equation

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I understand how the sequential gradient descend works, but I fail to understand the equation itself on how the next better weight wj is calculated. I can't visualize it graphically.

What exactly does the second term in the equation do? is it the slope on the selected point or is it the tangent on the point or what is it?

[image: SGD]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

To have an intuitive idea of what's going on consider the simple example of minimising the convex single-variable function: $J(w) = (w-4)^2$ where $w \in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly, this function attains its minimum $J^*=0$ at: $w^* = 4$. Note that $\frac{dJ}{dw} = 2w - 8$. Hence, our update equation reads:

$$
w_{i+1} := w_{i} - \alpha (2w_{i}-8)
$$

Now, let's imagine two scenarios: in the first, you have some $w_i$ which is bigger than 4. Not that, in such a case, $\frac{dJ}{dw}>0$. Hence, the update formula will make sure that $w_{i+1}<w_{i}$ in order to head towards the minimiser ($w=4$) (assuming $\alpha$ is positive of course). In the second scenario, i.e., $w_i <4$, we'll have $\frac{dJ}{dw}<0$ and the update formula will make sure that $w_{i+1}>w_{i}$ in order to head towards the minimiser.

Finally, $\alpha$ controls how big the difference between each consecutive steps is. The following two pictures depicts the objective function we're trying to minimise, and the $w_i$'s computed by the iteration formula for $w_0 = 7$ and two different values and $\alpha = 0.8$ and $\alpha = 0.01$ for the upper and lower pictures, respectively. Note that, with a bigger $\alpha$ you'll probably bounce back and fourth around the minimiser.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Saleh, all makes sense. Though, what I still can't visualize / fail to understand is what the second term in the equation produces. The slope on the given weight wj, a tangent or what?

Comment: Yes! The second term is the derivative of the cost function $J$ w.r.t. $w_i$. So it characterises how much $J$ changes for a small change in $w_i$. Notice, for example, that this derivative is very small if you are close to the minimiser $w^*=4$. Hence, if some $w_i$ is close to the $w^*$, the next iteration $w_{i+1}$ will not go so far. That's why it totally makes sense to use information from the derivative in the update formula.

Comment: Oh, thank yo so much @Saleh so the second term outputs the distance between the test point value and the actual value (y) of the function and this value is subtracted from the weight wj or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: No! The second term contains the derivative! It’s just that you can infer whether your estimations are far from the minimizer or not using your knowledge about the derivative. I suggest you read about derivatives of functions.